# unable to set replica set in mongodb3.2

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I am trying to setup a **demo replicaset** from `standalone MongoDB` in `MongoDB 3.2` with the following options in `mongod.conf`:

```
#replication:
 oplogSizeMB: 10240
 replSetName: "rs0"
```

But when I am trying to start mongodb it is throwing error:

```
Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. [FAILED]
```

output of journalctl -xe says:

```
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 runuser[29989]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 runuser[29989]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 mongod[29982]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Jul 02 07:53:56 smartJN3-LTest-Blr1 polkitd[2089]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:29977:8668980 (system bus name :1.114, object path /org
```

This is on `CentOS 7.2` . Thanks

Anyone any help. Thanks

Comment: can you add your setup replica set script ?
did you change the port of each mongod ?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it myself. stupid me, I didn't uncomment the section header `replication`, which is why the settings were never picked.